# How can I watch/follow a question?

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks, follow-posts

I come across many interesting recently asked questions on Stack Overflow. These questions might not be yet answered or other people might be still answering it.

Is there a way to watch/follow a question so that whenever it gets a new answer/comment, I get notified? If not where can I suggest this feature?

The only way I could find to do this is star the question and then eventually come back to it to see if it has been answered.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Starring/Favoriting

When you star a question, it gets added to your favorites, and it will be highlighted in your profile whenever it gets answered or modified:

[image: Screenshot]

### Question Feed

Below each question there is also an RSS feed that you can subscribe to:

[image: Feed screenshot]

Comment: Yes that's how I do it, but then I have to manually check it every few hours / days. Even after doing that I would not know that the question I am looking for has been answered / previously favorited question has been answered.

Is this feature worth requesting?

Comment: @user2834439 You can subscribe to the question feed by clicking the button on the bottom right hand corner of the page above the footer.

Comment: @Antony , Thank you. This seems like a solution. Then I can also remove feed when I no longer want an update. **Most importantly**, just because I want to follow a question, I don't have to star a question (which awards point to question asking person).

Comment: @user2834439 starring a question ***does not award points***.

Comment: Ohhhh. I was under this impression. Might have misread the **"how reputation works"** page. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @user2834439, If a question is interesting enough to follow, isn't it worthy of some internet points? I often see questions with stars and no up-votes, seems odd to me.

Comment: @Cup, I run [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/187928/users-with-most-favorites) then fed [your ID into my alpha app](http://brasofilo.github.io/stack.favs), it almost breaks :))

Comment: Sometimes I'll down-vote a question and I'd like to follow it to see if the user bothers editing/improving the question enough to warrant my removing the down-vote or considering an up-vote. Such questions aren't deserving of the "STAR I'm FAVORITING THIS" flair.

Comment: @fbynite (better late than never...) I want to follow a question when I suspect the OP will respond to my comment but not know how to `@` it to me. Prime example: asking a clarifying question on a weak question - it's not deserving of upvotes YET.

Comment: I really wondered how this works. I am often starring a question when I think it's of very good quality or reference - but I do not necessarily vote on it. It's a simple bookmark to me.

I'd have expected a "Subscribe" button like on GItHub. 
Nonetheless, I know that this could be simulated with the RSS feed.

Answer (score 30):

[Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) has some cool stuff to extend the interaction with the Stack family, like:

> ## [StackEye](https://stackapps.com/q/4454/10590)
>
> ### [Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on Stack Exchange sites](https://stackapps.com/q/4454/10590)
>
> *StackEye is a Chrome extension which can be used to follow other users for their answers and questions. Using StackEye you can also add a question to your watchlist there by getting notifications for each answer/comment on it.*
>
> **Watched questions will display notifications in the extension's popup window.**
>
> [image]
>
> **A list of watched questions is also available; questions can be unwatched in bulk from this screen.**
>
> [image]

Answer (score 21):

The ability to follow questions and answers is now a built-in feature in all Stack Exchange sites, including Stack Overflow.  A given question or answer can be followed by clicking the "follow" link underneath the question or answer.  Clicking it again unfollows it once more.

The questions you're currently following are listed in the ["Following" tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=following) of your user profile activity page.

This functionality was added to the Stack Exchange network on March 29, 2020.  The [Meta Stack Exchange announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) for this feature has details on its functionality and usage:

> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices. You will not receive notifications for any action that you performed.

[image: screenshot of question follow link]