# Not getting notifications for Updates on Answers and new comments in response to answers

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I am unable to get the notification when an answer is updated nor I am getting any notification when a comment is posted in any of the answers. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66488868/11877320) yesterday and it is causing such problems. I have to manually go to the question page to see any updates. I am using Mozilla Firefox on Ubuntu 20.1o

Comment: @yivi I created that post and I should be able to get all the updates regarding the question. Is not that so?

Answer (score 4):

That's not a bug, that's working as designed.

If you want to receive notifications on answer updates or on comments posted on answers, "follow" each of the answers.

You only get updates related to the question as defined by the system: New answers, new comments on the question, etc.

You are not notified of comments on answers [unless directly pinged, or you are the only other user to have commented on that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

And you do not receive notifications for edits unless you "[follow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397263/1426539)" the post.

Comment: I created that post and I should be able to get all the updates regarding the question. Is not that so?

Comment: @Jamshaid are you sure? 1 or 2 more years from now, you probably don't want getting any notifications from any activities on that question...

Comment: Frankly, it could be a good idea to give users to opt-in to all notifications should they choose to. During the downvotes discussion, it felt like a missing feature. That said, it certainly should not be a default option for the reasons already outlined.